# Can this bash function be optimized?

Tags: bash, function

Greetings,

I have a bash script that parses ZIP files we receive from a client and uncompresses them if a set of criterias is matched. It works well but it is slow. Particularly, the following function:

```
function getCTLfile() {
    for i in ${HDD_LIST_Array[@]}
    do
        if [[ `echo ${i}|awk -F . '{print $NF}'` == "ctl" ]]
        then
            echo "${i}"
        fi
    done
}
```

This function's purpose is to get name of the control file contained in a ZIP file. `HDD_LIST_Array[@]` is obtained thusly for each zip file:

```
HDD_LIST_Array=(`unzip -l $name | head -n -2|tail -n +4 | sort -r | awk '{print $4}'`)
```

Again, it works, albeit slowly. Can this function be optimized to run faster? Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: can you give us an example of the output of unzip -1 for your zip files, and the output of getCTLfile

Comment: unzip output  ===>>  
CTCA_HDD_20101108_150000.ctl
029045871901~Seagate~20101108~140021.HDD
028919111311~WD~20101108~140025.HDD
...

Comment: getCTLfile output ===>> Suffix is: ctl.

Comment: The latter allows me to check if our customer added to the ZIP a control file. IF there is not one, we kick off an email notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unzip -l` takes a file pattern to match after the input filename, and returns 0 on finding it or 11 on failure.

```
entry=$(unzip -l -qq "$name" '*.ctl')
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  awk '{ print $4 }' <<< "$entry"
done
```

Comment: Wow. Your approach is way more efficient than mine...Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Chris: You don't even have to involve AWK: change the first line above to `if entry=($(unzip -l -qq "$name" '*.ctl'))`, delete the second line and change the (former) fourth line to `printf "%s\n" ${entry[3]}`. Note that making assignments in conditional statements is frowned upon - you could do them separately, though, and still take advantage of using the array instead of AWK.

Comment: @Dennis: I am self taught. Could you please explain what making assignment in conditional statements is frowned upon?

Comment: @Chris: It's often done, but it an example of making use of [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science\)) which can often be the source of bugs and make code harder to understand. The example I showed makes an assignment, but relies on the exit code of the `unzip` to decide the conditional. If you didn't need the variable, you could test the `unzip` like this: `if unzip ...` which isn't so much a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cut` instead of `awk` and `&&` instead of `if` but that is probably minor if anything.  I would assume your largest wall-clock is the IO on the unzip, yes?

Put a `time` command around the whole call as well as prefixed to `unzip` to get your % differences.

OTHERWISE:  Looks like you want to just search and print for all files that end in `*.ctl` or something like that within a line-window (head|tail)?  Can you rather just `grep` or `sed` from your unzip output?  I'm betting an `unzip -l |awk` script will be sufficient.  I'll update answer as you provide more detail.

Comment: Correct. The unzip is what takes the most IO...I will see to use grep instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little comment to complement mobrule's reply.

The '-' appears in unwanted lines. You need two characters to differentiate, maybe a ':', or egrep '-[0-9]'